# Dynamic Tables , Column and values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I need to provide  Table name , Column name and Column values 
in an Oracle function dynamically. 
I have written a sample code in Oracle function , but it is not dynamic.

Can anyone help to make the below code to be dynamic , so that Table name , Column name and column values can be passed dynamically ?

```
Select test_emp_name ('Table name' , 'Column name' , 'column_value');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_emp_name (
     column_value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
     variable_1   VARCHAR2(100);
     variable_2    VARCHAR2(100);
     variable_3    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
     SELECT  max(Emp_Name)
       INTO variable_1
     FROM Employee_Table
     where Emp_Name = column_value

     variable_2 := SUBSTR( variable_1, 1,10 );
     variable_3 := SUBSTR( variable_1, 1,10  );

     RETURN         
       variable_2||variable_3;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN no_data_found THEN
     RETURN 'nothing found';
END;
```

Comment: I'm expecting an `execute immediate` somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure on how to pass attributes dynamically , any suggestions on the above code ?

Comment: . . Start with the documentation so you can learn what you want to do (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).  Actually providing the code isn't going to help, and I think teaching dynamic SQL is very broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Just a little consideration: "select max(xxx) from table" ALWAYS returns a row: that "exception when no_data_found" will never be raised, since MAX() of an empty set is null: that query will return a row containing null.